# Finding asset files, when developing & when installed (C++/Python, primarily on Linux)

Tags: python, c++, installation, assets, search-path

My project has a global asset directory (`/usr/share/openage`) that contains various files (graphics, texts, ...) and an user-specific asset directory (`~/.openage`) that allows the user to overwrite some of the global assets/add their own.

It is my understanding that when building, you pass the install prefix to the build system (e.g. `./configure --install-prefix=/usr`), which will in turn generate a file (e.g. `configure.h`) which makes the install prefix available for the code (e.g. `#define INSTALL_PREFIX="/usr"`). The code will then look for its assets in `INSTALL_PREFIX "share/openage"`. So far, so good.

However, when the project hasn't been installed yet (which is true in 99.9% of cases for me as the developer), the directory `/usr/share/openage` obviously doesn't exist yet; instead, I would want to use `./assets` in the current directory. Even worse, if the installed directory **exists** (e.g. from an independent, earlier install), it might data incompatible to the current dev version.

Similarily, if running the installed project, I'd want it to use the user's home directory (`~/.openage`) as user asset directory, while in "devmode", it should use a directory like "./userassets".

It gets even worse when thinking about non-POSIX platforms. On Windows, `INSTALL_PREFIX` is useless since programs can be installed basically anywhere (do programs simply use the current working directory or as the asset directory?), and I don't have the slightest idea how Mac handles this.

**So my question is**: Is there a generally accepted "best way to do this"? Surely, hundreds of projects (basically every single project that has an asset directory) have dealt with this problem one way or on other.

Unfortunately, I don't even know what to google for. I don't even know how to tag this question.
Current ideas (and associated issues) include:

- Looking for a file `openage_version`, which only exists in the source directory, in `cwd`. If it exists, assume that the project is currently uninstalled.

  - Issue: Even in "development mode", `cwd` might not always be the project root directory.
- Checking whether `readlink("/proc/self/exe")` starts with `INSTALL_PREFIX`

  - Issue: platform-specific
  - Issue: theoretically, the project root directory could be in `/usr/myweirdhomedirectory/git/openage`
- Forcing developers to specify an argument `--not-installed`, or to set an environment variable, `OPENAGE_INSTALLED=0`

  - Issue: Inconvenient
  - Issue: Forgetting to specify the argument will lead to confusion when the wrong asset directory is used
- During development, call `./configure` with a different `INSTALL_PREFIX`

  - Issue: When the project is built for installing, the recommended `make test` will run tests while the project is not installed
- A combination of the first two options: Checking for `dirname(readlink("proc/self/exe")) + "/openage_version"`

  - Issue: Even more platform-specific
  - This seems like the most robust option so far

Comment: I don't see how this is related to **Python**. If you're distributing / developing a Python application, the [resource manager API](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PkgResources#basic-resource-access) would be the proper way to get to your assets' data / paths. But all I see in your question seems to be `C++` related.

Comment: The application consists of both Python and C++; the implementation needs to work for both. The C++ code will load and use python packages for several tasks, but in order to load the Python Interpreter, it needs to know whether it is currently installed.

Comment: Set an environment variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I finally chose is to do the decision in the Python part of the application.

There is a python module, `buildsystem.setup`, which does **not** get installed during `make install`.

Using this fact, I can simply

```
def is_in_devmode():
    try:
        import ..buildsystem.setup
        return True
    except ImportError:
        return False
```